# FTP downloaded image is not displayed correctly

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, tomcat, ftp

I save user uploaded images in FTP.
FTP service is running on server `Server-A`. The actual problem is when I want to see the uploaded image from the web application running in my local host everything works, but when I deploy the local application to Tomcat running on the same server `Server-A`, images are not displayed correctly.

The picture when I run the web application in local Tomcat:

[image]

The same picture when I run the web application in the remote Tomcat:

[image]

You can see that the second image is not displayed correctly. Also want to mention that the FTP is the same one.

I am using Spring with Apache FtpClient library for image upload/download functionality.

Controller source code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:\\d+}/image", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
protected byte[] getUserImage(BaseForm form,
                              @PathVariable("id") int userId) {

    try {
        User user = checkToken(form.getToken());

        log.info("/users/{id}/image [GET]. User: " + user + ", form: " + form + ", User id: " + userId);

        FileWrapper image = service.getUserImage(userId);

        if(image != null) {
            return ftpService.downloadFtpFile(image.getName());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

FtpService source code:

```
public byte[] downloadFtpFile(String filePath) throws IOException {

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    try {
        client.connect(host, port);
        if(!client.login(username, password)) {
            throw new AdminException("Invalid ftp username/password");
        }

        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        try(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            client.retrieveFile(filePath, outputStream);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    finally {
        if(client.isConnected()) {
            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked what exactly is different in the files?

Comment: The file is the same in the same FTP. In one case I download file from the web application running on my local machine (it works), but in the second case I download the same file from the web application running on the remote machine, where is the FTP service is located (this file is not diplayed correctly).

Comment: Compare files you get on local and remote Tomcat. Obviously the second one is brocken, the question is what's the difference. Maybe the file gets truncated or maybe certain bytes are spoiled.

Comment: Have you tried setting the FTP to binary mode, as opposed to ASCII?

Comment: @lexicore The file sizes are equal. Please tell me how can I compare them.

Comment: @SteveSmith I set the FTP to binary mode when I upload files to FTP (client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);). Shall I also set to binary mode on downloading?

Comment: Yes.  If it's set to ASCII it will "convert the line endings" (or what it thinks are line endings).

Comment: @SteveSmith thanks a lot, it solved my problem. Can you please add this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @0bj3ct No probs, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've not set the FTP transfer to be binary (as opposed to ASCII) it will "convert the line endings" (or what it thinks are line endings) which will corrupt the picture.